# protractor shardTestFiles with cucumberOpt.tags starts unnecessary webdrivers

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I've noticed that when I use the shardTestFiles option to execute cucumber feature files in parallel across each browser type in multiCapabilities, it fires up a webdriver for each spec file + browser combo.  This happens regardless of whether the feature file contains a tag that matches the tags passed in via cucumberOpts.tags - instead it seems to check the tag match after the webdriver starts, and then for any features that do not have a match, it just says 0 tests and exits successfully.

This creates a lot of noise/capacity issues in the saucelabs console as it fires up a vm for each feature file regardless of whether it had anything to execute.  As a workaround we are  looking at executing a tag match across feature files before the  protractor grunt task in the same way that cucumberjs does in order to generate a list of feature file spec paths to put in the protractor conf, but this seems kind of hacky - anyone else seen this behaviour?

Comment: We have ended up executing the tag filtering logic from cucumberjs to create a list of feature files as part of constructing the protractor conf.   Works, but..

Comment: do you care to share that logic?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this stems from how `shardTestFiles` works. From what I understand (and it's all based on using the protractor-cucumber-framework package), if set to true, the specs are passed to Protractor's `TaskScheduler` and a webdriver session is started, then they are then run one-by-one using the framework's run method which in turn passes it to Cucumber's runner and only then is the tag filtering applied - so after the webdriver session is launched.

So your "hacky solution" is probably the best one out there right now, since sharding was not designed with Cucumber in mind.